# Keeping FPS in a certain range with three.js

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

Having an instance of `WebGLRenderer` created with `antialias = true` results in noticeable performance issues as resolution grows, especially on retina displays (`window.devicePixelRatio === 2`).

Since it's not possible to change the antialiasing mode on the fly, the question is: *how to automatically adjust the pixel ratio trying to keep FPS higher than a certain threshold (e.g. 30)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to monitor FPS in the rendering loop (by measuring intervals between `requestAnimationFrame` calls) and decreasing or increasing DPR accordingly.

"Monitoring" means recording those intervals into an array, removing min/max values (to avoid peaks), taking an average and comparing it with predefined thresholds.

```js
const highFrequencyThreshold = 20; // ~50 FPS
const lowFrequencyThreshold = 34;  // ~30 FPS

const minDpr = 0.5;
const maxDpr = window.devicePixelRatio;
const deltaDpr = 0.1;

const relaxPeriod = 4000;
const accumulatorLength = 20;

const frameTimestamp = performance.now();
const frequencyAccumulator = [];
const lastUpdatedAt = null;

const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
});

renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

animate();

function animate(timestamp: number = performance.now()) {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  monitor(frameTimestamp, timestamp);
  frameTimestamp = timestamp;

  // animation calculations and rendering
  // ...
}

function monitor(frameTimestamp: number, now: number) {
  collectFrequency(now - frameTimestamp);

  // accumulator is not fully filled
  if (frequencyAccumulator.length < accumulatorLength) {
    return;
  }

  // an update happened recently
  if (now - lastUpdatedAt < relaxPeriod) {
    return;
  }

  const dpr = renderer.getPixelRatio();
  const frequencyMedian = median(...frequencyAccumulator);

  if (frequencyMedian > lowFrequencyThreshold && dpr > minDpr) {
    updateDpr(dpr, -deltaDpr, now);
  } else if (frequencyMedian < highFrequencyThreshold && dpr < maxDpr) {
    updateDpr(dpr, deltaDpr, now);
  }
}

function collectFrequency(frequency: number) {
  if (frequency > 0) {
    frequencyAccumulator.push(frequency);
  }

  if (frequencyAccumulator.length > accumulatorLength) {
    frequencyAccumulator.shift();
  }
}

function updateDpr(dpr: number, delta: number, now: number) {
  renderer.setPixelRatio(dpr + delta);
  frequencyAccumulator = [];
  lastUpdatedAt = now;
}

function median(...elements: number[]): number {
  const indexOfMin = elements.indexOf(Math.min(...elements));
  const indexOfMax = elements.indexOf(Math.max(...elements));
  const noMinMax = elements.filter((_, index) => index !== indexOfMin && index !== indexOfMax);

  return average(...noMinMax);
}

function average(...elements: number[]): number {
  return elements.reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0) / elements.length;
}
```

Note that updating the DPR could result in short-time animation freezing.

Also, something more clever could be used for balancing the DPR value (rather than calling the `updateDpr()` with linear step of `0.1`), e.g. bisectional search.